# Show that $T$ is bounded and invertible in $L(H)$

Tags: functional-analysis

Define $T:L^2[0,1]\rightarrow L^2[0,1]$ by $$(Tf)(x)=f(x)+\int_0^x yf(y)df, f \in L^2[0,1], x \in [0,1]$$

How can we prove that T is a bounded operator? Also, how can we prove that $T$ is invertible in $L(H)$? For showing it is invertible, I have a hint saying "estimate $\|T-I\|$ where $I$ is the identity operator on $L^2[0,1]$". I have no idea how this hint helps me.

Comment: For boundedness: note that the operator is equal to the sum of the integral operator and the identity. With the identical operator everything is clear. And integral check by definition ($\|Af\|\leq c\|f\|$), using the Cauchy-Schwartz inequality. For invertible: show that $\|T-I\|<1$ (use Cauchy-Schwarz again).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll show you how the hint helps. (First show $||T-I||<1$).

Suppose $T$ is not invertible. Then $Tx=0$ has a nontrivial solution. Choose $x$ so that $||x||=1$. This equivalently solves $(T-I)x=-Ix$. Hence, $||(T-I)x||_2=||x||_2=1.$ By definition, $||T-I||=\sup_{||x||=1} ||(T-I)x||_2$. Hence, $||T-I||\geq 1$, a contradiction.